# How to str.join() in list of objects

Tags: python

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def __add__(self, other):
        return str(self) + other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return other + str(self)
```

I want that list of `A` objects to be "joinable" with [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).
Which [special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) should I implement to achieve this?

Of course, I can extract first a list of text then join it, but it's not what I want.

```
b = A('Hello')
c = A('World')
l = [b, c]

print b, c
print l
print b + ' ' + c
print ' '.join(l) # <- Error here

Hello World
[Hello, World]
Hello World
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sandbox.py", line 24, in <module>
    print ' '.join(l)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, instance found
```

Comment: "I can extract first a list of text then join it, but it's not what I want." - Too bad.

Comment: You've already implemented `__str__`, so you can use `' '.join(str(x) for x in l)`.

Comment: _List comprehension_ could be one way to reach your goal: `print ' '.join([str(item) for item in l])`.

Comment: Why not `A(' ').join(l)` and return a new instance of `A` containing the joined strings or a string instance?

Answer (score 12):

`__str__` is only used if the user of your object *wants* to turn it into a string, and `str.join` doesn't. You have to explicitly convert your objects to `str` values before `str.join` will use them.

(*Could* `str.join` have been defined to implicitly call `str` on each element in the iterable it receives as an argument? Sure. But it wasn't.)

One of the tenets of Python is "Explicit is better than implicit". If you want to `str.join` to join the string representations of your objects, *pass `str` objects to `join`*.

```
print(' '.join(str(x) for x in l))
```

The only way `join` will treat them as `str` objects implicitly is if they *are* `str` objects, which is to say if `A` is a subclass of `str`.

```
class A(str):
    def __new__(cls, text):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, text)
        # Do whatever else you need to add to obj
        return obj

l = [A('hello'), A('world')]
print(' '.join(l))
```

Beware of using inheritance where it isn't warranted, though.

Comment: Subclassing `str` just for that tiny detail is pretty much overkill, and could cause confusion in other parts where the class may come to be used. See [spaghetti inheritance](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/spaghetti-inheritance.html)

Comment: but OP _wants_ to be able to use `join`. That's pretty much the only way to do it.

Comment: He could use join along with list comprehensions. Much cleaner.

Comment: the technical explanation is spot on. "The only way to make ' '.join(l) work is if A is a subclass of str." doesn't mean that answered thinks that it's a good idea.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK Of course it is. The point of the answer is to display what you need to do for an instance to be treated *as* a `str`, which is to make sure it *is* a `str`.

Comment: @chepner you could add the alternative with `str` explicit conversion (which doesn't cost a dime if object is already a string). You'd have less enemies :)

Comment: @StefanPochmann I was thinking was something in the original question that I was going to have to add after calling `super`, but when I realized there wasn't, I didn't update the definition.

Comment: The way it's described will lead people to do exactly that, which is bad.

Comment: +1 now for the updated answer (which explains things better, and why only a subclass of str will do what the OP wants).